# How to use netstat command

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, netstat

My question is what does it mean to LISTEN or ACCEPT on a port as it relates to my example?

Example: I have a tomcat server, and It will use port 8080. I want to make sure that port is available for me to use.

What commands should I perform on my unix server and why?

what information would a command like this give me: `netstat -an | grep LISTEN`

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/488486/debian-port-80-is-blocked-but-i-dont-know-by-what/488491#488491

Answer (score 1):

You could try `sudo lsof -i :8080`.  That will list the processes doing anything with your port.

Comment: You have not answered any part of my question with this response.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use :

```
netstat -ant | egrep :8080
```

But its parameters:

```
-a : all
-t TCP protocol
-n numeric, don't use name
```

please attention to my example for port 80:

```
tcp        0      1 192.168.1.7:57511       182.50.136.239:80       SYN_SENT   
tcp        0      1 192.168.1.7:57547       182.50.136.239:80       SYN_SENT   
tcp        0      1 192.168.1.7:57512       182.50.136.239:80       SYN_SENT   
tcp        0      1 192.168.1.7:57514       182.50.136.239:80       SYN_SENT   
tcp        0      1 192.168.1.7:57562       182.50.136.239:80       SYN_SENT   
tcp        0      1 192.168.1.7:57565       182.50.136.239:80       SYN_SENT   
tcp        0      1 192.168.1.7:57513       182.50.136.239:80       SYN_SENT   
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.7:39191       198.252.206.25:80       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      1 192.168.1.7:57563       182.50.136.239:80       SYN_SENT   
tcp        0      1 192.168.1.7:57545       182.50.136.239:80       SYN_SENT   
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.7:39205       198.252.206.25:80       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      1 192.168.1.7:57546       182.50.136.239:80       SYN_SENT   
tcp        0      1 192.168.1.7:57564       182.50.136.239:80       SYN_SENT   
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.7:49217       198.252.206.16:80       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.7:39247       198.252.206.25:80       ESTABLISHED
tcp      957      0 192.168.1.7:42327       198.252.206.25:80       ESTABLISHED
```

First column is protocol, second : rec queue (numeric),3th: send queue(numeric) ,4th: local address+ port, 5th: foriegn host:port  , 6th: handshaking state such as LISTEN, SYN and so on.

Even you can use :

```
netstat -antp |egrep tomcat
```

I example mysql for u :

```
root@debian:/home/mohsen# netstat -antp |egrep mysql

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24783/mysqld
```

A new column has been appended, yes `pid/porgram`.